# How do I scale envelope warp proportions in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to scale everything proportionally, but the bulged text doesn't scale the same as the illustration. None of the envelope options helped. Using Adobe Illustrator CC 2019.

[image: Original size]

[image: When scaling everything up this occurs]

Comment: If you don't wanna edit text further how about expanding it? is it works?

Comment: Are you using the **Effect** menu item or the *actual* Envelope Distort in the **Object Menu**? The Effect has a tendency to be relative to the artboard rather than itself. The Object > Envelope Distort wont' suffer from the same limitation.